# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed,base {System.SystemException} = {"Invalid attempt to call Depth when reader is closed."}

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf-data-services, idatareader

getting this exception while retrieving the data using data reader from stored procedure. 
Invalid attempt to call Depth when reader is closed.Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed,base {System.SystemException} = {"Invalid attempt to call Depth when reader is closed."

```
base {System.SystemException} = {"Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed."}
base {System.SystemException} = {"Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed."}
  public DataSet FilteredGetProductsSearch(string ProductName,  int PageSize,int PageIndex)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductId");
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductPriceId");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("UrlRewrite");
            dt.Columns.Add("Description");
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");
            dt.Columns.Add("Size");
            dt.Columns.Add("Stock");
            dt.Columns.Add("Weight");
            dt.Columns.Add("MediaFilename");
            dt.Columns.Add("ThumbnailFilename");
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductName");
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductDescription");

        using (IDataReader reader = SPs.FilteredGetProductsSearch(ProductName,PageSize, PageIndex).GetReader())
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ProductId"] = reader["ProductId"];
                dr["ProductPriceId"] = reader["ProductPriceId"];
                dr["Name"] = reader["Name"];
                dr["UrlRewrite"] = reader["UrlRewrite"];
                dr["Description"] = reader["Description"];
                dr["Price"] = reader["Price"];
                dr["Size"] = reader["Size"];
                dr["Stock"] = reader["Stock"];
                dr["Weight"] = reader["Weight"];
                dr["MediaFilename"] = reader["MediaFilename"];
                dr["ThumbnailFilename"] = reader["ThumbnailFilename"];
                dr["ProductName"] = reader["ProductName"];
                dr["ProductDescription"] = reader["ProductDescription"];
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;

    }
```

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Comment: Yes, that's the *message*, but on what *line* of your code is the exception thrown?

Comment: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.this exception has occurred while executing the while loop

Comment: put this function `SPs.FilteredGetProductsSearch(ProductName,PageSize, PageIndex).GetReader()` in your question

Comment: Come to that though, why are you not just using [`DataTable.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) to have it import all of the rows?

Comment: while (reader.Read()) in this line,the exception was thrown @Damien

Comment: this is my code,used dataset and data table      public DataSet FilteredGetProductsSearch(string ProductName,  int PageSize,int PageIndex)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductId");
           
           .....................
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductDescription");

            using (IDataReader reader = SPs.FilteredGetProductsSearch(ProductName,PageSize, PageIndex).GetReader())
            {
                
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();@damien

Comment: get this exception at the while loop Empty "Enumeration yielded no results" string  @Damien